# Make any file unopenable in java

Tags: java, file, encryption, binary

I am creating some movie files in java. The file is in .mp4 format.
As the video is taken from a security surveillance camera, i want to make this file look corrupted when opened by anyone in any media player. The only way would be to decrypt the file by doing just opposite of what has been done with it while encrypting.

```
x = // byte read from file.
x = x >> 2;
// write x to new file
```

So basically i am looking for some way to encrypt the file (probably shifting every byte of file). I don't want to use complex algorithms like AES,DES or encryption with password.

What is the best way to decrypt/encrypt the file just by shifting the bytes. 
And Will this make the file look corrupted?

Comment: What you're suggesting is obfuscation, not really encryption. It provides no genuine security. If this is sensitive information, you really *really* should use proper encryption.

Comment: i don't really need any encryption kind of thing and obfuscation is the write thing that i want to achieve,

Comment: Complex encryption algorithms don't have to be complex to use, take a look around at the various encryption libraries available for Java, some will be no difficult than performing your own byte-shifting obfuscation...

Comment: So you're saying it's *not* sensitive information? Or that it *is* sensitive information, but you don't really care about it enough to use proper encryption? (As seanhodges says, this doesn't need to be tricky.)

Comment: You want to use something like DRM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management ?

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right.. i don't really care about it enough to use proper encryption

Comment: mask (xor) the whole file using a fixed byte sequence known to you.  undecoding is as simple as re-applying the mask to the file.

Comment: @jtahlborn should that be an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 5):

Some proprietary bit-twiddling algorithm is more likely to be buggy than using a well-known encryption algorithm.

As security is not a major concern for you, I would recommend you hard-code an AES key into your application and just do standard AES encryption/decryption of the data.

It's really very easy and there are a plethora of examples out there. It will be faster than inventing your own scheme and seeing if it works.

Answer (score 2):

That's more or less security through obscurity. It will probably stop the average joe to watch the video but a user with malicious intention won't succumb to some byte shifting/xor-ing or other quick encryption techniques.

At least introduce some key to encrypt the data. XOR with a key is simple to implement and as fast as it gets.

No movie player will be able to play such a file until decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with encryption it is generally best to use well known algorithms. It's not as complex as you might think (use encryption apis provided by the language of your choice, don'T rewrite stuff yourself)

If you shift the bytes as in your example you will not be able to get the old values back:
eg: you have 0xAB (10101011), you shift by 2 you end up with 00101010...how will you get the lost bits back?